# While trying to get a value of a set I get an error: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.6, openpyxl

I'm trying to find a cell with a certain value but keep getting TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

It happens on the line : idu = sh.cell[i,1].value

```
 elif 'To approve screenshot react with ' in reaction.message.content:
        sh=wb.active
        count = reaction.message.content.split('#')
        name = count[0]
        idududu = reaction.message.content.split('?')
        peepee = idududu[1]
        #await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), 'test' + peepee)
        idud = peepee.split('\nThe events the user has attended before are:')
        usid = str(idud[0])
        #await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), 'test' + usid)
        #await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), 'test' +str(usid))
        user=await client.get_user_info(usid)
        event = reaction.message.content.split('has attended a ')
        eventu = event[1]
        evento = eventu.split('Screenshot:')
        if reaction.emoji == get(client.get_all_emojis(), name='HYPERS'):
            await client.send_message(user, 'Your screenshot has been approved')
            await client.delete_message(reaction.message)
            i = 1
            while i < sh.max_row + 1:
                i=i+1
                idu = sh.cell[i,1].value
                if idu == usid:
                    if sh.cell[i,4].value is None:
                        sh.cell(row = i, column = 4, value = evento)
                    else:
                        ev = sh.cell[i,4].value
                        events = ev + ', ' + evento
                        sh.cell(row = i, column = 4, value = events)
                    x = int(sh.cell[i,2].value) + 1
                    await client.send_message(user, 'You have attended ' + x + ' events')
                    sh.cell(row=i,column=2,value=str(x))
                    await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), name + ' has attended ' + x + ' events.')
                    if x == 4:
                        await client.send_message(client.get_channel('560678137630031872'), user.mention + ' has attended 4 events and is now a ***FRICK***.\n@here')
                        sh.delete_rows(i)
                        sh.move_range(ws.iter_rows(i+1, sh.max_row),rows=-1)
                    wb.save(filename ="bot-counters.xlsx")
                    i=10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
sh.cell[i,1].value
```

With:

```
sh.cell(i,1).value
```

Reference: [Getting Cells from the Sheets](https://module-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/openpyxl.html#getting-cells-from-the-sheets)